# How to run Electron Application as a Windows Service

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, windows-services

I have an Electron Desktop App currently being started via `npm run start`

I want to turn this into a windows service so that it will start up automatically upon login. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to package your application, then you as example can add it into autostart. Here is how to package your application: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution

Comment: you should use a windows service wrapper such as Apache Commons Daemon for Java applications, NSSM (Non-Sucking Service Manager) for any type of executable, and Microsoft's own SrvAny.exe utility.

Answer (score 1):

You want to Google "Run and RunOnce Registry Keys."